# Gulp - jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, gulp

My gulp application seems to work fine but the jQuery doesn't get executed for some reason. I am new to Gulp and I can't figure out this issue.

This is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var stylish = require('jshint-stylish');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var fixmyjs = require("gulp-fixmyjs");
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = browserSync.reload;

// sass
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// js
gulp.task('js', function () {
    gulp.src(['./js/src/*.js'])
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(fixmyjs({
            "asi": true
        }))
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
            console.log(e);
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});

gulp.task('images', function() {
    gulp.src('./src/images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            progressive: true
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
});

// browser sync and watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        files: ['./**/*.php'],
        proxy: 'http://neontetra.local/',
    });
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass', reload]);
    gulp.watch('./js/src/*.js', ['js', reload]);
    gulp.watch('./src/images/*', ['images', reload]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'images', 'js', 'watch']);
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "neontetra",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/Automattic/_s.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/Automattic/_s)",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.17.3",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-fixmyjs": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.3",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

  }
}
```

And here is the main.js

```
(function($){
    "use strict";
    console.log('here');
    $('header').hide();
})(jQuery);
```

The console panel throws the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

What do I have to do for jQuery to work with Gulp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure that you download jQuery libraries before everything else?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried concatenating jQuery with gulp but it doesn't work. Now I have manually added jquery and it works..! I feel so silly. But is there a way to make jquery work through gulp? It seems strange that it breaks

Comment: @Jeff Why is it strange? How should gulp know that your HTML pages depend on jQuery? Should gulp inject it to your page?

Comment: No sorry I celebrated too early. Now gulp throws the error `'$' is defined but never used.` `events.js:141 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`

Comment: Gulp doesn't come with jquery included. Why? I'm guessing to avoid conflicts between jQuery versions.

Comment: Check the Jquery Libraries. Maybe you're using one that is not compatible with gulp. Go here ->> https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Comment: I was using version 3.x but also with version 1.12.4 it still gives the same error. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: `(function($){....` was not enough.. I had to wrap its content within `$(document).ready(function () {`. Thanks Wolfgang for helping me solving the issue

Comment: No worries man. One more thing about jQuery, This is what I usually do with scripts. I ALWAYS do (function($){   })(jQuery) ... I don't even do $(document).ready  anymore... This will assure you to not have conflicts within scripts. And if you're using several libraries where you'll have an OOP aproach, then I'll use require.js Super Asweome library that softwares as Magento uses in their core.

Comment: @WolfgangLeon, I am doing exactly what you mentioned, still it is failing for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43420591/uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined-even-though-jquery-is-first-impo

Comment: @daydreamer I see you have some libraries being loaded before main.js and you're using the latest JQuery Library. Some plugins aren't compatible with that version. 

Try changing the order of the libraries. Load Main.js first to see if the problem persists. Or you can try loading an older jquery version.

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangLeon, that helped me fix the issue, there were other issues as well. I documented my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43432879/379235

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple problems.

First, in the `index.html`, I removed the section

```
<!-- build:js scripts/main.min.js -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

which `gulp` uses to combine `JS` and minify them in 1 file. The fix was to add the following

```
<!-- build:js scripts/main.min.js -->
  <script src="scripts/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/vendors/waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

Secondly, in `gulp` `scripts` task, I had to tell `gulp` as to what all scripts to copy. The fix looked like

```
gulp.task('scripts', () =>
  gulp.src([
    // Note: Since we are not using useref in the scripts build pipeline,
    //       you need to explicitly list your scripts here in the right order
    //       to be correctly concatenated
    './app/scripts/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
    './app/scripts/vendors/waypoints.min.js',
    './app/scripts/main.js'
    // Other scripts
  ])
```

Lastly, as mentioned by `@Wolfgang Leon`, the `jQuery v3.2.0` was somehow incompatible, so I replaced it with `jQuery v1.9.1`

This helped me fix the issue completely. #learnednewthings